# Finding the number of Sylow p-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of finding the number of Sylow p-subgroups. Consider a group $G$ of order $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 105$. Now, let's find the number of Sylow 3-subgroups for this group: we have

$5 \equiv 2 \pmod 3\\7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3\\35 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$

So $1$ and $7$ are my options, by Sylow's third theorem. How do I determine which, in a none-bruteforce manner? (That is, I consider "we found $2$ so there must be $7$" a bad method. If you disagree strongly about this, feel free to present your argument and convince me, as long as you present a convenient method for the case where it is $1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to bruteforce insofar as the answer depends on details of the group. We could have $G\cong (Z_7\rtimes Z_3)\times Z_5$ where there are seven and we could have $G\cong Z_{105}$ where there is just one.

Comment: Just to be clear: given that we only know the order of the group, there is no way to determine whether its $1$ or $7$ in our scenario?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I didnÄt check though if the number of $5$-groups or the number of $7$-groups is fully determined. Or if there are still more groups ...

Comment: Well, they may only be fully determined if there is only one if we only know the order of the group, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: For a group of order $105$, the number of $5$-Sylows is exactly $1$, same for $7$-Sylows.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen, why isn't $21$ an alternative for $5$-Sylow? $7 \cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: You can show that we can find a subgroup of order $15$. A group of order $15$ is cyclic, so then a $5$-Sylow is normalized by a $3$-sylow. Hence a normalizer of a $5$-Sylow has order multiple of $15$, which shows that the normalizer must be the whole group.